# unable to pass parameter value inside Html.EditableGridView in mvc cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In MVC 4 project I tried to `pass parameter value` like following but I `failed due to syntax`.

In .cshtml file

```
   @(Html.EditableGridView<MyModel>("TestGridView",Model,Server.MapPath("~/XmlFile/Test.xml"),GridRowSelectionMode.Multiple,
  new { cssObj = "genericContentCss", url = "/Test/GetMyPartial?mode=Edit&id=" }))
```

> in url want to pass id parameter value like id=@Model.Id

but it is not working I'm missing something very small , I tried google but failed to do this can anyone give me clue

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
@Html.EditableGridView<MyModel>("TestGridView",
                                 Model,
                                 Server.MapPath("~/XmlFile/Test.xml"),
                                 GridRowSelectionMode.Multiple,
                                new { cssObj = "genericContentCss", 
                                      url = "/Test/GetMyPartial?mode=Edit&id="+Model.Id 
                                    }
                                )
```

or you can use `Url.Action()`:

```
url = Url.Action("GetMyPartial","Test",new { mode="Edit" , id=Model.Id })
```

in above code:

```
@Html.EditableGridView<MyModel>("TestGridView",
                                     Model,
                                     Server.MapPath("~/XmlFile/Test.xml"),
                                     GridRowSelectionMode.Multiple,
                                    new { cssObj = "genericContentCss", 
                                          url = Url.Action("GetMyPartial","Test",new { mode="Edit" , id=Model.Id }) 
                                        }
                                    )
```

Comment: My Model is a List<> :( can not getting Model.Id `Id` directly should I use @Model.Select(t=>t.Id) `will it take currently selected row Id`

getting 

`/GetMyPartial/Test/System.Linq.Enumerable%2bWhereSelectListIterator%602%5BMyModel%2cSystem.Guid%5D?mode=Edit`

Comment: @ashish If it is a collection then which id do you want?

Comment: @ehsan Sajjad I want selected row id column